# Create Spark UDF of a function that depends on other resources

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a code for tokenizing a string.

But that tokenization method uses some data which is loaded when my application starts.

```
val stopwords = getStopwords();

val tokens = tokenize("hello i am good",stopwords)

def tokenize(string:String,stopwords: List[String]) : List[String] = {
   
   val splitted = string.split(" ")

 
   // I use this stopwords for filtering my splitted array.
   // Then i return the items back.
  
}
```

Now I want to make the tokenize method an UDF for Spark.I want to use it to create new column in DataFrame Transformations.

I created simple UDFs before which had no dependencies like it needs items that needs to be read from text file etc.

Can some one tell me how to do these kind of operation?

> This is what I have tried ,and its working.

```
      val moviesDF = Seq(
        ("kingdomofheaven"),
        ("enemyatthegates"),
        ("salesinfointheyearofdecember"),
      ).toDF("column_name")
    
      val tokenizeUDF: UserDefinedFunction = udf(tokenize(_: String): List[String])
    
      moviesDF.withColumn("tokenized", tokenizeUDF(col("column_name"))).show(100, false)
    
    
      def tokenize(name: String): List[String] = {
    
        val wordFreqMap: Map[String, Double] = DataProviderUtil.getWordFreqMap()
        val stopWords: Set[String] = DataProviderUtil.getStopWordSet()
        val maxLengthWord: Int = wordFreqMap.keys.maxBy(_.length).length
    
        .................
        .................
      }
```

Its giving me the expected output:

```
+----------------------------+--------------------------+
|columnname                  |tokenized                 |
+----------------------------+--------------------------+
|kingdomofheaven             |[kingdom, heaven]         |
|enemyatthegates             |[enemi, gate]             |
|salesinfointheyearofdecember|[sale, info, year, decemb]|
+----------------------------+--------------------------+
```

> Now my question is , will it work when its deployed ? Currently I am
> running it locally. My main concern it that this function reads from a
> file to get information like stopwords,wordfreq etc for making the
> tokenization possible. So registering it like this will work properly
> ?

Comment: and what is exactly the problem?, what have you tried?

Comment: i added the thing that i have tried, if possible answer my last question . @EmiCareOfCell44

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point, if you deploy this code Spark will try to serialize your DataProviderUtil, you would need to mark as serializable that class. Another possibility is to declare you logic inside an Object. Functions inside objects are considered static functions and they are not serialized.

Comment: can you explain this line once more ? 'Another possibility is to declare you logic inside an Object. Functions inside objects are considered static functions and they are not serialized.'  @EmiCareOfCell44

Comment: Take a look to this post https://medium.com/@michaelpknopf/spark-serialization-errors-e0eebcf0f6e6 it explains the serialization problems